# how to change the text of LABEL and BUTTON during RUNTIME in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I just want to know how to change the text of the label and button during run time. Also how will I ID them differently when I draw them? I've already got the algorithm for Dragging and Creating them, and tried it successfully. My next goal is to how to change their text and how will i know if their IDs are different from one another?

Comment: The initial label text is whatever **you** assign it in the props window.  just reassign it at runtime.

Comment: Of course their ID's will be different, you can't assign the same name to more than one control.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Label1.Text = "My label"
Button1.Text = "My button"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm either missing something, or this is the easiest question ever...

```
Label1.Text = "New label text"
```

Comment: is that applicable during run time ? what i mean is when i double-clicked it for example, i can edit the text of the label and change it to something i want. thanks.

Comment: Well, yes, it's applicable at run-time.  However, what you are now asking is 'Is it possible to double-click on a label and edit the text?', in which case no, it's not.  A label is not user-editable at run time.  You would have to create a custom control to do that.

Comment: thank you for your answer Grim, i'll just find a way to create a control for that.